# Nginx permalinks in wordpress subdirectory?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, permalinks

I have nginx installed on my webserver but I cannot figure out the permalinking fix.

Is it because it's in a subdirectory?

```
#######################
# Permalinks

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri$args;
}
location /dir/wordpress {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri$args;
}
```

This should still work right?  if it was website.com/dir/wordpress?

Comment: If the URI for your website is `/dir/wordpress/index.php` then the last element of your `try_files` statement should be the same. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.